# Why does the button stop working after scrolling down on the page?

Tags: html, css

I added a button to open a modal when clicked. It works when at the top of the page but when you scroll further down and try to click it, the button no longer opens up the modal. I've put only the code used for the modal and button without the rest of the site code into it's own file to test it and it works just fine so it has to be something somewhere else in the code affecting it.
Here's the GitHub link: https://github.com/xman2156/TOH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button appears early in the markup, and is positioned but doesn't have a `z-index` set. However, it has later siblings which are also positioned without `z-index` set, notably `<div class="tab">`, which means it will appear on top of your button in the `z-index` and block clicks through to it.

If you apply `z-index: 1;` to your button, that will move it in front of the div that's currently in the way. If you need to ensure it's always on top of other content, you might find it useful to wrap the rest of your content in a single element that creates a separate stacking context, for example by applying `position: relative;`.

For some more information on stacking contexts and using `z-index`, here is a link that I find is a useful reference: [What no one told you about z-index](https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/)

Answer (score 0):

set z-index:1000 for both #info and #infoBtn
it'll solve your problem. I tried it.

Comment: I'd recommend avoiding using arbitrarily high `z-index` values, they can cause more pain down the line and often there's a simpler solution that can be implemented with a good understanding of stacking contexts.

Comment: thank you for sharing this resource. I've read it. I didn't know about that.